# Need help in reversing a banner loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, slideshow, reverse

All, I have been racking my brain for longer than I care, to admit trying to reverse this function. I have a loop set up so my slideshow starts on load, stops on hover, and can be navigated with next and previous buttons. When you switch directions, slides come from both directions and reset to one.

I'm pretty certain that this has to do with `var bannerStatus` being a global variable and resetting to one when changing directions. Is there any way to make the value not reset? Can I use a function to permanently update a global variable, or should I make one huge function that goes both ways? Here is my banner.js for this project.

```js
var bannerStatus = 1;
var bannerTimer = 3000;

window.onload = function() {
  bannerLoop();
}

var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
  bannerLoop();
}, bannerTimer);

document.getElementById("imgtabs").onmouseenter = function() {
  clearInterval(startBannerLoop);
}

document.getElementById("imgtabs").onmouseleave = function() {
  startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
    bannerLoop();
  }, bannerTimer);
}



function bannerLoop() {

  if (bannerStatus === 1) {

    document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {

    document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {

    document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 1;
  }
}

function reverseBanner() {
  if (bannerStatus === 1) {

    document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {

    document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {

    document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 1;

  }

  document.getElementById("nxtbtn").onclick = function() {
    bannerLoop();
  }

  document.getElementById("prvbtn").onclick = function() {
    reverseBanner();
  }
```

```css
#imgtabs {
  background-color: hsl(43, 0%, 93%);
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

#ban1 {
  background-image: url(imgs/Romans%20Group.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ban2 {
  background-image: url(imgs/AlphaMailTruck.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ban3 {
  background-image: url(imgs/Romans%20Group.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tab h3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 2%;
  color: white;
}

.imgbtn {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgbtn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.prvbtn {
  left: 5px;
}

.nxtbtn {
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="imgtabs">

    <div class="tab" id="ban1">
      <h3>First</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="ban2">
      <h3>Second</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="ban3">
      <h3>Third</h3>
    </div>

    <a class="imgbtn prvbtn" id="prvbtn">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="imgbtn nxtbtn" id="nxtbtn">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML so I could test it?

Comment: Yes, there is no point to create a snippet if it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I'm new here. I didn't realize I needed all that. I'll put that up after work today. Thank you for the quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

## If Something is Reversed Then Go the Opposite Direction

> ```
> document.getElementById("ban1").style.left
> ```

### Demo

```js
var bannerStatus = 1;
var bannerTimer = 3000;

window.onload = function() {
  bannerLoop();
}

var startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
  bannerLoop();
}, bannerTimer);

document.getElementById("imgtabs").onmouseenter = function() {
  clearInterval(startBannerLoop);
}

document.getElementById("imgtabs").onmouseleave = function() {
  startBannerLoop = setInterval(function() {
    bannerLoop();
  }, bannerTimer);
}



function bannerLoop() {

  if (bannerStatus === 1) {

    document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {

    document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {

    document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.right = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.right = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.right = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 1;
  }
}

function reverseBanner() {
  if (bannerStatus === 1) {

    document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.left = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.left = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.left = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 2) {

    document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.left = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.left = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.left = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus++;
  } else if (bannerStatus === 3) {

    document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.left = "100%";
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.zIndex = "900";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.left = "0px";
      document.getElementById("ban2").style.zIndex = "1000";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.left = "-100%";
      document.getElementById("ban3").style.zIndex = "1100";

    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("ban1").style.opacity = "1";
    }, 1000);

    bannerStatus = 1;

  }

  document.getElementById("nxtbtn").onclick = function() {
    bannerLoop();
  }

  document.getElementById("prvbtn").onclick = function() {
    reverseBanner();
  }
}
```

```css
#imgtabs {
  background-color: hsl(43, 0%, 93%);
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

#ban1 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/5LPXSfn/Lenna-test-image.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ban2 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/tmQZgJb/68eb2df1a189f88bb0cbd47a3e00c112.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ban3 {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tab h3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 2%;
  color: white;
}

.imgbtn {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1200;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgbtn:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.prvbtn {
  left: 5px;
}

.nxtbtn {
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="imgtabs">

    <div class="tab" id="ban1">
      <h3>First</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="ban2">
      <h3>Second</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" id="ban3">
      <h3>Third</h3>
    </div>

    <a class="imgbtn prvbtn" id="prvbtn">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="imgbtn nxtbtn" id="nxtbtn">&#10095;</a>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```